# how to implement discount value in invoice using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying implementing  a discount value getting in my form.

I tried this in jQuery code

```js
$('tbody').delegate('.quantity,.price,.gst,.dsc', 'keyup', function() {
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  var quantity = tr.find('.quantity').val();
  var price = tr.find('.price').val();
  var gst = tr.find('.gst').val();
  var dcs = tr.find('.dcs').val();
  var totalamountgst = (quantity * price * gst) / 100;
  var totalamountdcs = (quantity * price * dcs) / 100;
  var totalamounts = (quantity * price + totalamountgst);
  var totalamount = (totalamounts - totalamountdcs);


  tr.find('.totalamount').val(totalamount);
  total();
});

function total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.totalamount').each(function(i, e) {
    var totalamount = $(this).val() - 0;
    total += totalamount;
  });
  $('.total').val(total + ".00");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control quantity" name="qty[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="QTY" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control gst " name="gst_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="GST" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control dcs " name="dcs_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="DCS" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="number" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control price" name="purchase_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="RATE" value="" required pattern="" numbers="" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalamount" name="" id="validationServer01" placeholder="AMOUNT" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @mplungjan out put result showing wrong. "108"                                                                         
    |   QTY    gst(tax)        discount(dcs)   RATE        amount  |
    |     1          18%                   10%        100             108       |
           Right result "106"                                                                                                                                      
     |   QTY    gst(tax)        discount(dcs)   RATE       amount  |
     |     1          18%                   10%          100           106     | fix this

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Please look at the calculation you wrote  - I just copy the result and sum it - please show input and expected output on all fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had typos and missed a total.

You really also should test for empty and isNaN when ppl enter non-digits or make them all type=number

```js
$('tbody').on('input', '.quantity,.price,.gst,.dsc', function() {
  const $tr = $(this).closest("tr"); // parent row
  const quantity = $tr.find('.quantity').val() || 0; // value of input fields
  const price = $tr.find('.price').val() || 0;
  const gst = $tr.find('.gst').val() || 0;
  
  const $dcsField = $tr.find('.dcs'); // the field is cached so we can reuse
  const dcs = $dcsField.val(); // here is the value

  const totalamountgst = (quantity * price * gst) / 100;
  const totalamountdcs = (quantity * price * dcs) / 100;
  const totalamounts = (quantity * price + totalamountgst);
  const totalamount = (totalamounts - totalamountdcs);
  
  $dcsField.data("dcsamt",totalamountdcs || 0); // save the discounted value in a data attribute to be summed

  $tr.find('.totalamount').val(totalamount.toFixed(2));
  total();
});

function total() {
  let total = 0,
    totalQty = 0,
    totalDcs = 0;
  $('.totalamount').each(function(i, e) {
    const totalamount = $(this).val() - 0;
    total += totalamount;
    const q = $(this).closest("tr").find(".quantity").val() || 0;
    const d = $(this).closest("tr").find(".dcs").data("dcsamt") || 0;
    totalQty += q - 0;
    totalDcs += d - 0; // take the actual discount from the attribute
  });
  $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
  $('#totalitems').val(totalQty.toFixed(2));
  $('#totaldcs').val(totalDcs.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control quantity" name="qty[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="QTY" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control gst " name="gst_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="GST" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control dcs " name="dcs_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="DCS" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="number" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control price" name="purchase_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="RATE" value="" required pattern="" numbers="" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalamount" name="" id="validationServer01" placeholder="AMOUNT" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control quantity" name="qty[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="QTY" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control gst " name="gst_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="GST" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control dcs " name="dcs_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="DCS" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="number" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control price" name="purchase_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="RATE" value="" required pattern="" numbers="" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalamount" name="" id="validationServer01" placeholder="AMOUNT" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control quantity" name="qty[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="QTY" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control gst " name="gst_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="GST" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control dcs " name="dcs_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="DCS" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="number" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control price" name="purchase_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="RATE" value="" required pattern="" numbers="" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalamount" name="" id="validationServer01" placeholder="AMOUNT" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" disabled></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="text" class="text-danger input-lg form-control" id="totalitems" name="" placeholder="TOTAL ITEMS" value=""></td>
      <td></td>
      <td> <input type="text" class="input-lg form-control" id="totaldcs" name="" placeholder="TOTAL DCS" value=""></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" readonly id="total"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is there possible show entire discount amount as well total filled rows ,like showing total amount

Comment: can you post answer i spent 3 hours i getting error only please help

Comment: i dont understand that

Comment: i whant to show total dcs amount and total filed row

**<!-- below input shows total dcs amount -->**
'<td > <input type="text" class=" input-lg form-control totaldcs"  name=""  placeholder="TOTAL DCS" value=""></td>'

**<!-- below input shows total filed row -->**
'<td > <input type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalitems"  name="" placeholder="TOTAL ITEMS" value="" ></td>'

Comment: thank you for help. your are correct DCS is a discount total,

Comment: my question is I'm trying to displays total DCS amount (discount amount ), it means.  example. 1st row has ( 750*0.48 = 360 ) 750 is total amount , 0.48 (48%) is discount  and 360 is discount amount  my question is i what  to calculate  discount amount of each row. at the same time i want to count total filed row . example i used 2 row it show 2 ,in case 3 rows it show count 3,

Comment: I believe my code above has ALL the ingredients to do whatever you decide.

Comment: yes i agree, i want small help mplungjan, im also coding like my need but output  it not coming. i dont have that much of knowledge in jQuery so i need help, please help to get as i required  result

Comment: yes its math. if you give some time for me i will explain what i need

Comment: my last hope is you pleas help, i will explain one more time,

Comment: @mplungjan i think  user12380208 not post his answer mplungjan can you fix this its major part of calculation help

Comment: Is user12380208  not your user too? With this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498667/how-to-implement-total-discount-value-and-total-filed-row-using-jquery)

Comment: @mplungjan i am getting error NaN in DCS in run code snippet

Comment: @mplungjan if i enterd QTY column DCS getting error NaN

Comment: @mplungjan please check your answer and enter some value you will get error

Comment: Ok fixed. Forgot you do not loop first but also loop when not all fields are entered